# Array as subscript

Tags: matrices, arrays, subscripts

While `$\begin{matrix} 2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3 \end{matrix}$` looks great for the highest root of `$\mathsf E_8$`, `$s_{\begin{matrix} 2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3 \end{matrix}}$` looks awful.  I can get closer to a reasonable result using `$s_{\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3 \end{smallmatrix}}$`, but it seems like there must be some variant of an `array`/`matrix`-type environment that resizes automatically in subscripts and other appropriate contexts.  Does such a thing exist, or must I use some combination of `\mathchoice`, `matrix`, and `smallmatrix`?

As an added bonus question, what parameter controls the space before and after an `array` or `matrix` environment?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be so disruptive: `$s_{\mbox{\tiny$\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3 \end{smallmatrix}$}}$` but I would think that using a matrix as subscript in in-line math is not the best choice.

Comment: `smallmatrix` already uses `\subsubscriptstyle` for the entries, which is 5pt size for a default 10pt size. Going under 5pt means asking your readers to buy a magnifying lens.

Comment: @egreg -- maybe i'm misreading something, but `smallmatrix` in `amsmath` uses `\scriptstyle` (7pt for default 10pt), and isn't boxed, so in a subscript, that would get kicked down to the smaller size (5pt, the usual equivalent of `\tiny`), but what you're saying implies that `\smallmatrix` *always* uses the `\tiny` equivalent.  also, the only way i know (with most document classes) to go smaller than 5pt is to use something like `\scalebox`.  (and yes, that's not good for the eyes; even with a magnifying glass, you may be up against the output device resolution.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think you're right, I wrote based on memory (which probably failed). But no, it wouldn't change size in subscripts, because it's `\halign` with `\hfil$\m@th\scriptstyle##$\hfil` as template

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I agree that, in general, matrices don't make good subscripts; but, in this case, it's not 'semantically' a matrix, just a row of numbers in which one happens to be lowered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a variant of `smallmatrix` that uses `\scriptscriptstyle` instead of `\scriptstyle` for the entries. Also `\vcenter` should be changed to `\vtop` so that the top line goes at the level of normal subscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\tinymatrix\smallmatrix
\let\endtinymatrix\endsmallmatrix
\patchcmd{\tinymatrix}{\scriptstyle}{\scriptscriptstyle}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tinymatrix}{\scriptstyle}{\scriptscriptstyle}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tinymatrix}{\vcenter}{\vtop}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tinymatrix}{\bgroup}{\bgroup\scriptsize}{}{}

\begin{document}
$s_{\begin{tinymatrix}2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3 \end{tinymatrix}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of the three patches you could define it by editing the definition of `smallmatrix` from `amsmath`:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tinymatrix}{\null\,\vtop\bgroup\scriptsize % smallmatrix has \vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@\restore@math@cr\default@tag
  \baselineskip6\ex@ \lineskip1.5\ex@ \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup\hfil$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil&&\thickspace\hfil % smallmatrix has \scriptstyle
  $\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr % smallmatrix has \scriptstyle
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup\,%
}
\makeatother

If you want to use a single command for all styles, then it's necessary to use `\mathchoice`:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tinymatrix}{%
  % removed also \, from left and right
  \null\vtop\bgroup\scriptsize % smallmatrix has \vcenter\bgroup
  \Let@\restore@math@cr\default@tag
  \baselineskip6\ex@ \lineskip1.5\ex@ \lineskiplimit\lineskip
  \ialign\bgroup
    \hfil$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil&&\thickspace\hfil % smallmatrix has \scriptstyle
    $\m@th\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil\crcr % smallmatrix has \scriptstyle
}{%
  \crcr\egroup\egroup
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\spicematrix}[1]{\mathchoice
  {\spicematrixaux{matrix}{#1}}
  {\spicematrixaux{matrix}{#1}}
  {\spicematrixaux{tinymatrix}{#1}}
  {\spicematrixaux{tinymatrix}{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\spicematrixaux}[2]{\begin{#1}#2\end{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A \spicematrix{2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3} B
\\
\textstyle A\spicematrix{2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3} B
\\
s_{\spicematrix{2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change your mind about text style, change the second `{\spicematrixaux{matrix}{#1}}` into

```
{\null\!\spicematrixaux{smallmatrix}{#1}\!}
```

so as to remove the thin spaces on the left and right of `smallmatrix`.

Comment: there's a somewhat simpler way that doesn't involve redefining anything, though it uses a similar idea and some gentle persuasion:  `s^{\vphantom{y}}_{\text{\tiny$\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ && 3 \end{smallmatrix}$}}`

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, what I'm most interested in is having a command that will behave properly inline, and in subscripts, without explicit instructions or selection from me.  Does such a thing exist, or do I have to build it myself (I guess with `\mathchoice`)?

Comment: Also, I have trouble navigating my way through the se@ of `@`s.  Which of these commands is responsible for the spacing around an `array` / `matrix` / `smallmatrix` environment?  In particular, is there any easy way (preferably without patching commands) to get rid of that space on an *ad hoc* basis?

Comment: @LSpice How should it behave in displayed math?

Comment: @egreg, I'm not really sure what is most pleasant to the eye, but I'd be fine with something that behaved like `matrix` inline *or* in display mode, and like `smallmatrix` (or the shrunken version you describe) in subscripts.  (If there's some better choice for display math, then I don't mention it only out of ignorance.)

Comment: This is great, thanks.  I am proud to have lent my name to the [`\spicematrix`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melange_%28fictional_drug%29).  :-)